# Featured Question missing

Tags: support, pagination, featured-tag

I currently have a problemen with the featured questions of SO. There are currently [401 featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=9&sort=featured), but the last page of the featured questions tab does not display any question.

When i hit F5 (Shift + F5) to reload the page, the question is displayed a minimum time and than vanishes.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the question: [How to get the value of the textbox which created dynamically with the Raduploader in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899380/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-textbox-which-created-dynamically-with-the-radupload)

It has five tags: [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [telerik](/questions/tagged/telerik).

You have one of those tags in your "ignored tags" list plus you have "hide ignored tags" in your prefs:

> [image]

This caused the question to be hidden after the page is loaded.

Comment: ok, i see. First time that i observe this behavior. Thanks for clarification

Comment: Where can I find the option *hide ignored tags*?

Comment: In your profile under preferences ("prefs")

Comment: @hims056 http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1369235 :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - direct link. *Page Not Found* for you :)

Comment: @hims056 yep I know, changed the URL manually.. :D